# Extra characters in socket receive buffer using async socket example from msdn .net 4.5

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous

I'm kinda baffled about this...what are the trash characters on the front of the received data...same set of characters every time.  I've tried this and other examples...same thing.

Waiting for a connection...
Waiting for a connection...
Read 32 bytes from socket.
 Data : ??▼?? ??↑??'??☺??♥??♥asdf
 : 32
Sent 32 bytes to client.

I'm simply loading and running this example...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Comment: Well, what data did you *send it*? and how?

Comment: in the case of the pasted example...I sent "asdf" to the server via a telnet connection and the server printed all the extra characters before "asdf".

Comment: 2 secs while I check with telnet...

Comment: I also had the sentinel value of <EOF>

Comment: it worked fine via telnet for me; no garbage

Comment: what **exactly** did you send it? what exactly did you do? sending "asdf" would not create 32 bytes... I get 11 bytes, which corresponds exactly to "asdf\r\n<EOF>"

Comment: I sent exactly "asdf<EOF>" and got that...maybe I have incorrect putty settings?

Comment: I was using Active telnet negotiation.  Switching to passive fixed it.  :-\

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any trash characters; the following is fine:

```
static void Client(object state)
{
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.NoDelay = true;
        client.Connect(localEndPoint);
        using (var ns = client.GetStream())
        {
            string data = @"this is 
some random data
with multiple lines
<EOF>"; // <=== server explicitly expects this as a sentinel value

            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // note: normally I'd use Socket etc; ReadToEnd is
            // ... unreliable on a NetworkStream
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ns))
            {
                // for this ^^^ to end, it means the server disconnected
                // the socket, which means it got the <EOF> and shutdown
                string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("From server:");
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static int Main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Client);
    // ^^^ client on a different thread to the server
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the error is in the "client" code, which you aren't showing us. Presumably it is not ASCII-encoded text, which is what the server is expecting.